# QuickFIXJ- Session Deactivated - Does the session auto logon on its specified time?

Tags: quickfixj

Acceptor is vendor party which has specified session time. AFTER that boundary, we are gettinglogout Reason in fromAdmin callback( 35 = 5) . We are simply sending false status to UI. Now my question is: the other day ,will the acceptor auto logon to session when it's session time start? As when logon happens, we are sending True status to UI which the user can understand and start creating orders.

Comment: Yes, providing you've set up the proper start time and end time in your QuickFIX/J configuration.

Comment: Also keep an eye on the time zone config if your counter party is in another time zone.